# Advance arduino programming?

Tags: programming, arduino-ide

I have worked with basic arduino IDE for making robots and sensor based projects.Now I want to learn some advance arduino programming and try some complex Arduino projects.Can anyone help me with the links or related information..?

Comment: You could learn about what algorithms are if you want to delve into "advanced programming". If you believe yourself to be rather adept, then get into computational theory. Perhaps learn about _finite state machines_ or _object oriented programming_ but there aren't any **readings** for Arduino advancements. Just become a better programmer. Learn some Python. Learn how to program an Arduino with different programming languages.

Comment: get an ESP8266 to run some of your AVT sketches; the conversion will teach you a lot about the ardunio platform, and MCUs in general.

Answer (score 3):

Here are 4 suggestions:

> Especially for point 2 there are plenty of resources that are easy to find. Once you learn "Blink" sketch,you will realize there is a lot out there.

1. Don't use Arduino IDE

It lacks a lot of features which any serious programming IDE offers today. Visual Micro for Visual Studio and PlatformIO are two examples. More alternatives mentioned in the comments. These IDE which give you advance features like syntax highlighting, autocompletion, multifile projects, etc..

2. Start learning C/C++

Arduino programming is derived from C++ with some nice libraries to make it easier, specially on Embedded Systems. Instead of looking up and setting registers to change pin state Arduino libraries will make it easier for you.I have worked with complex projects on arduino and arduino libraries made it very easy to go. There is a lot more to learn in arduino.

3. Start learning electronics

Your advanced projects surely comes with advanced electronics. This is a whole other place where things might go beyond our understanding. I have spent hours and days debugging my codes. It will also help you find your way through the jungle of all the current "maker toys". There are different platforms, variety of boards and chips,people often spend a lot of time figuring out which one is suitable for our project.

4. Have a look at Arduino's "successors": ESP8266, ESP32

These Chinese chips are like Arduino on crack. They have onboard WiFi and higher clock frequencies (but are also a lot more capricious and don't have as much documentation as Arduino). Best part: You can program them just as easily as your Arduino Or you can try barebone programming (javascript)later. The newest one, the ESP32 is a dual-core chip with 240 MHz, WiFi and Bluetooth. Cost is around USD 2. It is available on Aliexpress.
There are also a lot of other chips/boards out there that I have not mentioned here. Above is AFAIK the most common.

Comment: 1b.  Don't use Visual Micro and Visual Studio, the overhead isn't worth the benefits IMO.  Use Notepad++ as an external editor for the Arduino IDE.  It has all the features of Visual Studio 2017 + it has macros!  (Otherwise Grtschnk is spot on!)

Comment: I want something like Netbeans (clean and lean), with refactoring, integrated source control (Git), library managment, and local copies (not Internet) of all docs (pins, specs and API's). Free (as beer) and for Linux.

Comment: Try eclipse then. There's already a good plugin for that to support Arduino.

Comment: @Delta_G. I hate Eclipse so much. It is a big mess of add-on and plug-ins for this and that. It's not even an option for me.

Comment: I don't see how netbeans was any better.  They're just about equivalent to me.  I haven't had any issues with eclipse. I use it for Java, python, c++, Arduino, and I'm sure something else I'm not thinking of this early in the morning.  Either way, it was just a suggestion. You don't have to take it.